# Plastic and plastics

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between **plastic** and **plastics** when referring to the things made of plastic?

> - The **plastics** used in food packaging are a breeze to recycle: you just melt them down and reform them
> - In exchange for the convenience of using **plastic,** you also give up something some people hold dear-privacy.

Answer (score 4):

In the first example, plastics is a noun that refers to multiple kinds of plastic material used in packaging. A plastic bag may be composed out of a different kind of plastic from a plastic water bottle, for instance.

In the second example you give, "plastic" is being used as a [metonym](https://www.google.com/search?q=metonymy&oq=meton&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j69i57j0l2.795j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for credit card, as in the title of this book: [Paying with Plastic: The Digital Revolution in Buying and Borrowing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00307SDXQ)

Plastic can also be an adjective that refers to malleability.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic):

> **Plastic** is material consisting of any of a wide range of synthetic or semi-synthetic organic compounds that are malleable and so can be molded into solid objects.
>   **Plastics** are typically organic polymers of high molecular mass and often contain other substances.

The word ‘**Plastic**’ refers to something which is flexible or malleable. Although most synthetic polymers are flexible, there are a many materials which also have these properties including lead, butter, clay, and beeswax.

The word ‘**Plastics**’ refers to polymeric materials… these can be synthetic or natural, thermoset or thermoplastic, and semi-crystalline or amorphous.
([Source](https://routsis.blog/2011/01/plastic_vs_plastics/))

Comment: sorry you missed that the plastic in this case was a metaphor for a credit/debit card